# Out of memory in PHP

Tags: php, caching

I am having a problem with memory in PHP. I am required to obtain a huge report, a table with a lot of information.

This information is obtained also via some complex functions, which means that it cannot be obtained as the user requests it, as he/she would have to wait around 5 minutes for the information to be displayed.

I was caching the result, but as the information grew, now the browser just crashes and does not show anything. What are possible solutions for this?

I was thinking on storing the data in mysql instead of cache, and then execute a couple of selects when the user requests the information. What do you think about that solution? Any other better options?

***Update***

Looks like the problem was not understood, so I add more detail.

A search is being used already. There are many points to be kept in mind:

1) The information itself has to be calculated. I have a cron running that builds it (takes like 5 minutes), and stores it in cache. The browser is just rendering from cache, and the search is searching on this cached data. The information cannot be obtained in real time.
2) That is why I was thinking on storing the calculated results in MySQL, that way the search can search in the MySQL table, instead of searching the cached data (which is huge and impossible to handle now by the browser).

I hope the problem is more clear now!

Comment: Are you really getting a browser crash? If that's the case, I doubt it really matters how you obtain the information that's sent to the browser.

Comment: I would suggest pagination if it is possible. Give information in chunks. Add search for users, so they wouldn't need to loop through every page in pagination. I think, that the problem is not in memory amount, but in how much rendered content browser can handle.

Comment: I don't think I got it right. Are you launching a script that has to do some huge calculation via browser? That's not really wise.

Comment: Added more details to explain better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think storing the data in mysql is good idea specially if you build some indices on frequently queried data columns , caching will consume large memory (it often store data in RAM) .

Another thing you should consider , try to view server logs (access, and error) logs because you could find your solution there

and finally hope you solve your probelm

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, you should paginate the output if it is possible. I think storing data in MySQL is not great idea...

Comment: MySQL is designed to store data

Answer (score 0):

check the php.ini setting for this parameter

```
memory_limit = 512M
```

set it to some more value